# How can i create this multiple activities one after another

Tags: android-activity, fragment

[Activity 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmEJW.png)

[Activity 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd57j.png)

How can i create these multiple activity when i have to put textView and ImageView data in every activity.

Comment: To start one activity after one other or moving between activities you need Intents. Intents can also pass data along with them. For more check here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: yes! I know intents can do the job! But is there any other way of doing it. like with fragments? or any other

Comment: Yes you can use Fragments. But Fragments need an Activity in order to exist. So you will end up having 1 Activity and 2 Fragments. Activity will be responsible for communicating between the two fragments. I recently wrote a documentation here on SO for this communication - http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1396/fragment/23663/communication-between-fragments#t=201609281037138579377